# Laravel 4: Input::get() is not working

Tags: php, laravel-4

Something weird is happening in my production server using CentOS 7 and the problem is... in my local environment I have many applications developed with Laravel 4 and were installed in servers like CentOS 6.5 or 7 and works very well but this is not working in this part:

- I can't get the variables with Input::get('my_get_variable'); neither in the controller or in views because always return NULL.

I really don't know what's happening and hope you can help me.

It's not working using the form or not using it executing manually in the url.

**View Form**

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'GET', 'action' => 'CompanyController@search', 'class' => 'f-search')) }}
    <input type="search" id="search-text" name="s" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Buscar empresas..." required>
    <select id="search-category" name="c" class="form-control input-lg">
        <option value="">Categoría</option>
        @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <optgroup label="{{ $category->name }}" id="{{ $category->id }}">
                @foreach ($category['subcategories'] as $subcategory)
                <option value="{{ $subcategory->id }}" id="{{ $subcategory->id }}">{{ $subcategory->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </optgroup>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Buscar">
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/buscar','CompanyController@search');
```

**Controller**

```
//Search
public function search()
{
    $term = Input::get('s');
    $category = Input::get('c');

    var_dump($term);
    var_dump($category);
}
```

**UPDATE**

When I use $_GET['s'] instead the Laravel get function, it returns this: Undefined index: s

**2nd UPDATE**

I changed the GET to POST and now works fine but Idk why is not working with GET.

Thanks to those who tried to solve this!

Comment: If you do Input::all() do you get any results?

Comment: I'm trying to get the 's' and 'c' variables but if I print Input::all() I just can get this: array(1) { ["query_string"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: @SoldierCorp Sounds like your form is being sent using the GET method.

Comment: @RichardA Yes, is for search function.

Comment: I think you should paste "view" (form) code, and controller code.

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius Code added

Comment: Does the URL ever change to `/buscar?s=something&c=something`? For a `GET` request, that's the only way you're going to get `Input::get("s")` or `Input::get("c")` to work.

Comment: Yes, always change the url in every request.

Comment: What differences are there between production and development servers? Are they both running Apache? Is production behind a reverse proxy? Are your rewrite rules the same for both?

Comment: Have the same... I'm using nginx in my production server and Apache in my local server but I have the same for another apps

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue lies on your .htaccess file on the server. The RewriteRule is not properly done. Find the similar line and fix as follows.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA]
```

[QSA] is the changed section

Comment: yes and thanks. change RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA] resolves problem

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'GET', 'action' => 'CompanyController@search', 'class' => 'f-search')) }}
```

Try changing `'action'` => `'buscar'`.

Comment: Or you could remove the action if he's already on `/buscar`, right?

Comment: Personally I define route name for ex. register: Route::post('users/register', array('as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'AuthController@registerAction')); and then I use it for form 'action' => 'register'

Comment: Yeah, I've seen named routes before, they work well too, I just mean that it should default to the page he's on if `action` was removed.

Comment: You are right, but in this case, element SEARCH could be on every page, so it won't work :)

Comment: Using 'action' => 'buscar' is not working but the action is ok I guess because in the html source result can see the exactly url of the route in the action attribute.

Comment: Is very weird because also in the view I got NULL using Input::get('s') or Input::get('c') but in local can get both variables without any problem.

Comment: What if you manually go to page website.com/buscar?s=abc ? vardump returns null again?

Comment: Yes is null :/ I'll try with an ajax function using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a test locally using the following settings:

```
// routes.php
Route::get("/test", "AppController@test");

// AppController.php
public function test() { 
  print_r(Input::get("test"));
  return View::make("test");
}

// test.blade.php
<form method="GET" action="{{ URL::to("test")}} ">
  <input type="text" name="s" class="form-control">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

After pressing `Submit`, the url changes to `localhost/sotests/test?s=test` and the page returns with "test" printed right above the form.

Some changes, I used `URL::to("test")` as my action. I don't know if that will fix your issue, but it worked like a charm for me. Other than that, I also didn't use Laravel's `Form` class, but I don't think that would make a difference.

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Hi! Locally works fine as my other apps and also this example but not in my server with CentOS 7 even I'm using another CentOS 7 in another droplet with another application and works fine but not with this :/

Comment: Huh. How odd. Something has to be configured improperly, cause I've got nothing if that didn't work... I can't fix something I can't replicate. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, don't worry Tim I understand. I wish to know if someone had the same issue to check how to solve it but as I told to Eimantas, I'll try with an ajax function using jquery. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, hope you get this fixed. Cheers!