# laravel form with get method wrong parameters

Tags: forms, laravel, get, request

hi and thanks for replies. i hove a form like this:

```
    <form action="{{route('searchpages')}}" method="get">
    <input class="form-control" name="query"  placeholder="search" type="text">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">search</button>
    </form>
```

and a route:

```
Route::get('/searchpages','PageController@searchpages')->name('searchpages');
```

and controller:

```
    public function searchpages(Request $request){
        $query= $request->get('query');
...
```

every thing in windows local host is ok and when user type for example `apple`, `$query` variant will be `apple`.
but in shared house the `$query` variant is always `null`!!!
in local host:

```
+request: ParameterBag {#50 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "query" => "apple"
    ]
  }
```

but in shared host:

```
  +request: ParameterBag {#50 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "/searchpages" => null
    ]
  }
```

and search results URL is:

```
http://example.com/searchpages?query=apple
```

I think its may something wrong in host. like `.htaccess` or ... . what do you think? 
the big problem is deference between local and online host that produces dummy bugs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally and after pay many hours the problem resolve according to: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28323596/5320087)
i just replaced:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA]
```

in `.htaccess` file of host.
thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to get variable with input() function

```
$query= $request->input('query');
```

and do not change route or method to post.it  should be get.
also try doing:
`$query= request('query');`

Answer (score 0):

dont forget to add

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

if you dont im sure the next error will be token mismatch exception

and do not change route or method to post.it should be get. also try doing: `$query= request('query');`